# Embedding an uploaded svg using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am uploading an svg using jQuery and file tag:

HTML:

```
 <input type='file' />
 <img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function () {
$(":file").change(function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
});

         function imageIsLoaded(e) {
             $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
  };
```

SVG is uploading fine and showing on image tag. Problem is, I need to embed svg into html not only show it as image.Any idea how to get svg code and embed it on html?

Comment: I just added the decode part to help you a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to refer you to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

There it says that you get back a base64 encoded string with a data attribute. So in order to get the clear text you need to remove "data:* / *;base64," (in your case probably image/svg+xml for the * / *, but you can look that up in the dev tools) in the beginning and than do a base64 decode. After that you should be able to put the svg directly into the dom.

Decoding:

```
let base64 = e.target.result.split('base64,')[1];
let clear = atob(base64);
```